# Rails - can't connect to Digital Ocean Managed MySQL

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ssl, digital-ocean

I'm trying to connect my Rails app to Digital Oceans Managed MySQL, and not having much luck.  Running Rails 6, Ruby 2.6.3 - Error is quite ambiguous for me:

```
    00:30 deploy:migrating
      01 $HOME/.rbenv/bin/rbenv exec bundle exec rake db:migrate
      01 rake aborted!
      01 Mysql2::Error::ConnectionError: SSL connection error: unknown error number
      01 /home/deploy/my_app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/mysql2-0.5.2/lib/mysql2/client.rb:90:in `connect'
      01 /home/deploy/my_app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/mysql2-0.5.2/lib/mysql2/client.rb:90:in `initialize'
      01 /home/deploy/my_app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:24:in `new'
      01 /home/deploy/my_app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:24:in `mysql2_connection'
      01 /home/deploy/my_app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:879:in `new_connection'
      01 /home/deploy/my_app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:923:in `checkout_new_connection'
      01 /home/deploy/my_app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:902:in `try_to_checkout_new_connec…
      01 /home/deploy/my_app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:863:in `acquire_connection'
      01 /home/deploy/my_app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:587:in `checkout'
      01 /home/deploy/my_app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:431:in `connection'
      01 /home/deploy/my_app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:1111:in `retrieve_connection'
      01 /home/deploy/my_app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:231:in `retrieve_connection'
      01 /home/deploy/my_app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:199:in `connection'
      01 /home/deploy/my_app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.0/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:238:in `migrate'
      01 /home/deploy/my_app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.0/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:85:in `block (3 levels) in <main>'
      01 /home/deploy/my_app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.0/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:83:in `each'
      01 /home/deploy/my_app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.0/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:83:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
      01 /home/deploy/my_app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rake-12.3.3/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
      01 /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
      01 /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
      01 Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
      01 (See full trace by running task with --trace)
#<Thread:0x00007fd33a9096a0@/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/sshkit-1.20.0/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:10 run> terminated with exception (report_on_exception is true):
Traceback (most recent call last):
    13: from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/sshkit-1.20.0/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:12:in `block (2 levels) in execute'
    12: from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/sshkit-1.20.0/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:31:in `run'
    11: from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/sshkit-1.20.0/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:31:in `instance_exec'
    10: from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/capistrano-rails-1.4.0/lib/capistrano/tasks/migrations.rake:23:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
     9: from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/sshkit-1.20.0/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:92:in `within'
     8: from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/capistrano-rails-1.4.0/lib/capistrano/tasks/migrations.rake:24:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
     7: from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/sshkit-1.20.0/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:100:in `with'
     6: from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/capistrano-rails-1.4.0/lib/capistrano/tasks/migrations.rake:25:in `block (5 levels) in <top (required)>'
     5: from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/sshkit-1.20.0/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:80:in `execute'
     4: from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/sshkit-1.20.0/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:148:in `create_command_and_execute'
     3: from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/sshkit-1.20.0/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:148:in `tap'
     2: from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/sshkit-1.20.0/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:148:in `block in create_command_and_execute'
     1: from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/sshkit-1.20.0/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:170:in `execute_command'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/sshkit-1.20.0/lib/sshkit/command.rb:97:in `exit_status=': rake exit status: 1 (SSHKit::Command::Failed)
rake stdout: Nothing written
rake stderr: rake aborted!
```

My.cnf:

```
[mysqld]
pid-file        = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
datadir         = /var/lib/mysql
log-error       = /var/log/mysql/error.log
# bind-address    = 0.0.0.0
bind-address = *
require_secure_transport = ON
```

Database.yml (url string provided by digital ocean)

```
production:
  adapter: mysql2
  url: mysql2://doadmin:alkdfjlsdkjfl@my-app-mysql-do-user-65417-0.db.ondigitalocean.com/defaultdb?ssl-mode=REQUIRED
  pool: 15
  timeout: 5000
  sslca: /home/deploy/ca-certificate.crt
  socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

Comment: "SSL connection error: unknown error number" You have a problem in connection to mysql over an SSL connection. Look at MySQL logfiles maybe about connection attempts that failed, and try manually connecting with any mysql client using the same parameters to see why the connection does not succeed to the server

Comment: Have you tried connecting from the terminal, maybe you can find the actual error code there.

Comment: Yes I can connect from the terminal no problem.

Comment: I can connect fine from my local machine but not from my droplet using the same credentials.